# List with ng-if in angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to use ng-if in angular.js. I have a json file:

```
"data":[{
   "status":"true",
   "name":"blabla",
   "group":true,
   "group_id":"123gr",
   "id":"xx1"
},{
   "status":"true",
   "name":"blabla2",
   "group":false,
   "id":"123gr",
   "group_id":"null"
}]
```

And from this JSON I try to get a list of all groups (group in JSON must set be true) and then list group's elements. So I want to have a list that looks:

- Group: blabla2.

  - Element 1: blabla. Status: true

I tried to list just a group name.. in this way:

```
<ul>
   <div ng-repeat="resp in response.data">
        <li ng-if="{{resp.group}} === 'false'">
          Group: {{resp.name}}
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Thank you for your help,

Luke

Comment: The `ng-if` expression doesn't need to be parsed and your `group` properties are booleans, not strings. Ergo ~ `ng-if="resp.group"`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work..

Comment: Updated, try now. I thought you wanted it when `resp.group` was `false`

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a list with 2 elements: blabla2 and blabla

Comment: try ng-if="{{resp.group}}"

Comment: Already tried.. no results.

Comment: @Vineet no, don't do that

Comment: Your JSON is malformed and `<div>` does not go in `<ul>`

Comment: Will you please elaborate Phil ? Or share any URL, so I can learn more.

Comment: @Vineet see first comment.

Comment: @Luke It's missing a comma after `"group":false` in the second data item

Comment: Thank you Phil. I will take care further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could remove those altogether if you don't need them by filtering them out of `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="resp in response.data | filter: {group: true}">
        Group: {{resp.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Bad spot for a `<div>`, just put the `ng-repeat` on the `<li>`

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
<ul>
    <div ng-repeat="resp in response.data">
        <li ng-if="!resp.group">
            Group: {{resp.name}}
        </li>
    </div>
</ul>
```